# upper bound for the number of solutions of a diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider the positive integers less than or equal to one trillion, i.e.,
$$1, 2, 3, \dots, 10^{12}-1, 10^{12}.
$$
Prove that less than a tenth of them can be expressed in the form
$x^3 + y^3 + z^4$,
where $x, y$, and $z$ are positive integers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you work out how many perfect cubes $≤10^{12}$ there are?

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! For this problem, what are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like we're being asked to solve contest problems or do other people's homework; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^3+y^3+z^4\le 10^{12}$, then $x^3, y^3, z^4\le 10^{12}$, so $x, y\le 10^4$ and $z\le 10^3$.

Now, even if every possible triplet $(x,y,z), 1\le x, y\le 10^4, 1\le z \le 10^3$ gave you a distinct sum $x^3+y^3+z^4$, and if all those sums were also up to $10^{12}$, this will still produce up to $10^4\times 10^4\times 10^3=10^{11}$ sums, which is exactly one tenth of all the numbers between $1$ and $10^{12}$.

In fact, we get strictly fewer than $10^{11}$ sums because:

- Some different triplets $(x,y,z)$ give you the same sum $x^3+y^3+z^4$, in particular: swapping $x$ and $y$ does not change the sum. (E.g. $1^3+2^3+3^4=2^3+1^3+3^4$).
- Also, some triplets give you a too big sum (e.g. $(10^4)^3+(10^4)^3+(10^3)^4=3\times 10^{12}>10^{12}$).